# Extract Pie Chart (other similar charts) data from PDF using Python

Tags: python, pymupdf

Help me in extracting the pie chart data from attached PDF using Python.
PDF: https://i.dell.com/sites/csdocuments/CorpComm_Docs/en/carbon-footprint-poweredge-m630.pdf

Thanks in Advance
Santhosh

I have tried using PyPDF2, PyMuPDF libraries. Since am new to Python, not sure of all available methods and other libraries to achieve this.

Comment: That Pie Chart is just an image. Using PyMuPDF, you can create a list of images on the page `page,get_images()`, optionally look at the area each one covers `page.get_image_rects(img)`, and extract an image based on this info via `img = doc.extract_image(img)`. The save extracted `bytes` object as an image file or do whatever analysis with it.

Comment: More often than not, such graphics (pie charts, Gantt charts, etc.) however **are no images** but vector graphics. They will not be identified by the above methods. But PyMuPDF also offers to identify vector graphics, an either extract those directly as a list of single drawing elements (lines, curves, rectangles), or render parts of the page to convert them to an image file.

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using the PyPDF2 library.

1. Convert PDF to Image using PyMuPDF lib or pdf2image to convert the PDF pages to images.
2. You could install pdf2image using: `pip install pdf2image`
3. Use an image processing library like OpenCV or PIL to analyze the pie chart image and extract data, and finally once you've successfully extracted the image data, you can use image analysis techniques to determine the size or percentage of each slice in the pie chart.

Here's a small example using OpenCV

```
#Load the image
image_path = 'path/to/your/image.png'
image = cv2.imread(image_path)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#Thresholding
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

#Find contours
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

#Print the number of contours (slices in the pie chart)
print("Number of slices:", len(contours))

#Draw the contours on the image
cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

#Display the image
cv2.imshow('Image with Contours', image)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to analyse any PDF object before deciding on Method so for the given example the PDF rendering is actually a scaled down copy of the internal image resource and thus it is the image you need to extract to maintain quality.

[image]

Thus in this case poppler pdfimages would be a good method. You can either run that instantly whilst viewing the PDF (and making the decision) or from Python use poppler from  a shell command.

[image]

If you extract all images at once there is no need to run page by page, as in this case, the page 2 images will also be output to the same folder.

[image]

Note that OCR will not usually be able to recognise data at an angle such as along the bottom edge only those at 0 or 90 degrees as seen on the Left
[image]

However for horizontal text OCR is not usually a problem
[image]